# Symfony 3 - Manage two authentication modes, logout problem

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, cas

on symfony I have to develop an application that can manage the connection through a form on the site, but also a CAS connection.

When it comes to a connection directly to the site (for external users), they must have a form.

For the CAS connection (users internal to a service that are part of an LDAP), when they go to the site, they are automatically redirected to a connection site, and they will be redirected to the right site once connected.

For the connection of external users, and their management, I use FOSUserBundle.
For CAS authentication, I use a bundle that my company has developed to redirect to the login page and then get the user's information.

The problem is that this is the first time we develop a project that must take into account several types of connection, and inevitably, there are conflicts that we do not understand.

So, this is my code :

**Security.yml:**

```
# app/config/security.yml

security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

providers:
    app:
       id: bes_auth.user_provider

firewalls:

    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
       # anonymous:    true

    main:
        logout_on_user_change: true
        pattern: ^/

        guard:
            authenticators:
                - app.security.login_form_authenticator
                - bes_auth.authenticator

            entry_point: Site\PagesBundle\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator

        logout:
            path:   /logout #nom de la route de déconnexion
            target: /
            success_handler: bes_auth.authenticator
        anonymous:    true

access_control:

    #    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    #   - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    #  - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/.*, role: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/profile/.*, role: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/logout, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

**rooting.yml:**

```
# app/config/routing.yml
fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"

auth_cas_logout:
    path: /logout
```

**services.yml:**

```
############ Guard with FOSUserBundle ##############

app.security.login_form_authenticator:
    class: Site\PagesBundle\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
    autowire: true


################ CAS ###########################    

Site\PagesBundle\Security\Auth\AuthCasService:
    autowire: true
    parent: Besancon\AuthBundle\Security\Abstracts\AuthAbstract
    public: false  
    autoconfigure: false
```

**config.yml:**

```
# FOS User Bundle
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Site\PagesBundle\Entity\User
    service:
        mailer: fos_user.mailer.twig_swift
    registration:
        form:
            type: FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType
            name: fos_user_registration_form
            validation_groups: [Registration, Default]
        confirmation:
            enabled: true
            template: '@FOSUser/Registration/email.txt.twig'
    profile:
        form:
            type: FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\ProfileFormType
            #validation_groups: [Profile, Default]
    resetting:
        email:
            template: '@FOSUser/Resetting/email.txt.twig'
    group:
        group_class: FosSf3\MainBundle\Entity\Group
    from_email:
        address: mail
        sender_name: username


besancon_auth:
    use_default_provider : true
    user_entity: ~
    homepage: "homepage"
    authentication_service: Site\PagesBundle\Security\Auth\AuthCasService
    type_auth: Cas

    cas:
        hostname: "######.######.fr"
        port: ###
        uri: ""
```

I can log out using the "logout" in the bar at the bottom of the page. By cons, using the disconnect button, I return to the home page and I'm not disconnected.

**My base.html.twig :**

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{{ path('deconnexion') }}">Déconnexion</a>
```

**My controller function:**

```
/**
     * @Route("/logout", name="deconnexion")
     */
    public function deconnexionAction()
    {
        $token = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken();
        //dump($token->getAttribute('nomComplet'));

    $typeAuth = $token->getAttribute('typeAuth');
    dump($typeAuth);

    if($typeAuth == 'cas')
    {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('auth_cas_logout');
    }

    else
    {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('fos_user_security_logout');
    }

}
```

I edited the route of the deconnexion function to /logout , and the link works now! However, it immediately redirects me to the SESHAT (the authentication page of our service) and I would like to be redirected to the home page to choose how I want to identify myself. But anonymous access does not work

Comment: Why does your deconnexion route go to "/" ?

Comment: Effectively. I changed and I set to / logout, and the link works now! However, it immediately redirects me to the SESHAT (the authentication page of our service) and I would like to be redirected to the home page to choose how I want to identify myself. But anonymous access does not work

Comment: I edited my first post with my new code

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to modify your **access_control** in **Security.yml** to

```
#    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
#   - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
#  - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
- { path: ^/admin/.*, role: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN }
- { path: ^/profile/.*, role: ROLE_USER }
- { path: ^/logout, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
- { path: ^/.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

Because it seems like your logout route is not accessible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! So I changed the code, and the problem is always the same. It would be necessary to be able to have two logout in fact. One that would be effective for external users, and one that would apply to users who have had CAS authentication. And in my code, it would be up to me to handle the call of one or the other of these logout depending on the type of the user

PS : sorry for my bad english, I'm French

Comment: I will edit my first post to add my logout function